# How to custom the save button on editor using RichFaces 4?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, save, richfaces

I am using the **RichFaces 4** in my **JSF** application, but I`d like call a method from my bean when the user press the save button (for example: to save in a file text.txt)

Is there a way to call a java method when the user click on rich:editor save button?

Here is the code i`m using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
    <http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <h:head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
   <title>Insert title here</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>


       <h:form>


    <rich:editor id="editor" toolbar="full" value="#{editorBean.value}"
        style="margin-bottom: 1em" height="400" >


        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="panel"  status="panelUpdateStatus" />

        <a4j:ajax event="dirty" render="panel" status="panelUpdateStatus">
            <a4j:attachQueue requestDelay="1000" />
        </a4j:ajax>



    </rich:editor>

    <rich:panel id="panel">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Output from Editor
            <a4j:status name="panelUpdateStatus">
                <f:facet name="start">
                    (Updating)
                </f:facet>
            </a4j:status>
        </f:facet>
            <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{editorBean.value}" />

    </rich:panel>


</h:form>
```

EditorBean

```
 import java.io.Serializable;


 import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
 import javax.inject.Named;

 @Named
  @SessionScoped
  public class EditorBean implements Serializable{

 /**
 * 
 */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 5383915229820571701L;


 private String value;

 /**
 * @return the value
 */
 public String getValue() {
    return value;
 }

 /**
 * @param value the value to set
 */
 public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
 } 

 public void save(){
    System.out.println(" Saving ");
    //Code to save
 }
}
```

Comment: Is an extra button as suggested by @W vd L acceptable or do you *need* to override the save icon functionality?

Comment: Actually an extra button was a simple way to do it and i already knew this way, but i`d like to make it following the pattern used in aplications (the disket at the upper left corner) to make my application closest to the routine from my user and pass a better experience to him. And i think that if they`ve put this disket icon must have a way to use it for something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <editor></editor>
  <a4j:commandButton value="Ok" type="submit" execute="@form" action="{editorBean.save()}" />
</form>
```

Bean:

```
public void save(){
    System.out.println(" Saving: " + this.value);
    //Code to save
}
```

This should submit the form, so the editor value gets saved to the bean. 
When pressing the button, the editor content should show in your System.out.